# jQuery select option selected when click on option

Tags: jquery

Here is my code Snippets
HTML Code

```
<select name="options">
   <option value="0" selected="selected">all</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

jQuery Code

```
$('select[name=options]').change(function(e) { 
    // $(this).attr('selected',true); CHANGED AS BELOW
    $(this).find(':selected').attr('selected',true);
});
```

This jQuery code adds attribute to `<select>` I want it on which option I click it automatically set selected.

Comment: Why do you need to add a `selected` attribute to the selected option? What you choose is already selected right?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is the default behavior. You don't need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: I'm with Stephan it is already selected but I believe for selected in jquery it is .attr("selected","selected");  or .prop("selected", true); are you trying to find the value of the selected option? if so just use .val()

Comment: You could just get the current selected value  using JQuery. The selected item has a selected by default

Comment: I actually wants to set selected because I want to make search by value and when I select any option and submit It automatically set to default and I am not able to get the result. I changed my code and get the results but when I select another option it set `selected` but didn't set others `selected false`

Comment: having a difficult time understanding your requirements. are you saying you have some sort of search box tied to the values in the drop down? and when they enter the value in the search box the drop down is automatically selected?

Comment: When they select any one of value from drop down and submit the selected option from drop-down value could be found.